# Why are my neighbor's front yard sprinklers causing a large water build up on my front lawn?

Tags: lawn, drainage, sprinkler-system

Whenever my neighbor's sprinklers go off it leaves a huge amount of water on my lawn. How come this is happening?

See large puddle around the tree:

[image]

Comment: I’m sorry, but I don’t “see” - your photo is very blurry. Could you please add a few details, like is there a slope, what kind of soil do you have and have you talked with your neighbor about it? (I guess he would also prefer the water on his plants instead of in your yard.

Comment: From the little that can be seen, it looks as if the lawn may be slightly higher than the soil around the tree - if you could post another, clear photo taken in daylight, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

From the picture it looks like the tree, and part of your wall is down slope from the drainage part of the neighbors yard, if you put some dirt on top of it it will then slope away from your wall and tree.